# Configure Firewall port 8080 to open Utorrent

Tags: networking, server, xubuntu, firewall, utorrent

I'm using Xubuntu and I want to use uTorrent. I did the steps from this tutorial: http://idroot.net/linux/install-utorrent-ubuntu-16-04/

I already enabled the Firewall. Set to default policies

```
sudo ufw default deny incoming

sudo ufw default allow outgoing
```

Allow http connections

```
sudo ufw allow http
```

But when I want to access uTorrent at  http://my-ip-adress:8080/gui 
I get the following message:

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 192.168.1.73:8080.

```
The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

What am I missing?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it work if you turn ufw of?

Comment: Are you trying to access it from the local LAN or externally?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you've allowed connections to port 80 not 8080.

You should allow it directly like that:

```
sudo ufw allow 8080/tcp
```

or by its service name *http-alt*

```
sudo ufw allow http-alt
```

Comment: Already did it :C do I have to open it at my modem configuration too?

Comment: If you allow it in firewall but still can't connect to that port from same computer then we should search another problem. In that case can you please post output of command "**ss -tnl**" so we can see if anything even listen that port.
And about modem: if your modem work as router with NAT then you should redirect that port to your computer to make it accesible from external network.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply...  apparently I was missing the last step, starting the uTorrent server (utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/ &) I have to make this every time I turn on my PC. Thanks again, you are so kind